# Sqlyog error 1452

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog, mysql-error-1452

I'm having problems with the foreign keys.
I have a table DETAILS that contains general details with the NAME being the primary key and another table SYMTOMS with two columns NAME and SYM. I have tried to refernece DETAILS to SYMPTOMS through NAME buy i get error 1452
Please help.

I tried setting foreign keys checks to 0. now the error doesnt occur but what i want is this query to work

```
select SYM from DETAILS where NAME='a';
```

It doesnt work. it says details table doesnt have a col SYM but I have linked them through foreign key.

DO i need to use apply JOIN. If yes,Please give the statement

Comment: what do you mean "linked through fk"? Just because two tables have a foreign key between them doesn't mean that table #2's fields will be visible in table #1's. You still have to actually `JOIN` them together in the query.

Answer (score 1):

you must use join between the tables

```
      select SYM from DETAILS 
      INNER JOIN SYMTOMS 
      ON SYMTOMS.,,,, = DETAILS.,,,,   --- // fill those comma by the relation between the two tables , 
      where NAME='a';
```